# Eclipse cannot recognize common type

Tags: eclipse

I'm coding on a dynamic web project. After a while, my eclipse just cannot recognize very common classes such as "HttpServlet" (please see the attached image). I don't remember changing any setting in Eclipse or the project. And this issue happened many times before, not only for this project. My own only solution is create another project and copy my code. It works for a while, but then the problem came again. Please, it's such a pain. Any tips or hints will be really helpful!

Attached image - this is how my project looks like now:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to import `servlet-api.jar` in your build path.

`properties-> build path -> configure build path -> add external jars`.

select `servlet-api.jar` from your tomcat folder.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! it works now. But I'm really curious that why when I create the web project it works perfect, I don't have to add this lib that time. How come after a while (3 day for this project), till now it shows me the error?

Comment: @Suanmeiguo you are welcome, if the answer has solved your problem then you must accept it

Comment: `How come after a while (3 day for this project), till now it shows me the error?` i m not sure but I think you are getting this error after adding servlet, so this jar file is needed in servlet for `HttpServlet` and others thats why it was giving errors

Comment: I just accept it! I use servlet at the beginning of this project created, not now. So if it needs the jar, it should remind me 3 days ago.

Comment: @Suanmeiguo ok, usually eclipse shows this error when we create servlet or use any class which needs this `jar`, i am not sure why eclipse doesn't given you this error for three days

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add an import statement.

   `import javax.servlet.*;`
2. Make sure that the jars containing the `javax.servlet.*` are added to the classpath of your project.

Comment: i think OP needs to include `servlet-api.jar` in his build path

Comment: there are many jar files that will give him the required classes.

Comment: ok, i know `servlet-api.jar`, can you tell me other ones, it will update my knowledge

Comment: I am not sure but i think he has already imported `javax.servlet.*;`, because I think he has created this servlet from eclipse, and those lines of code is automatically written by eclispe

Comment: goto findjar.com. enter the name of the class you are looking for and you will get all the jar files that contain the classes you searched for.

Comment: Like he mentioned on your answer 'now it works' so he did not have the jars in the classpath

Comment: Great website to look up jars! Thank you Mayank